# make the scrollbar css visible in the web page

Tags: css, angular

I'am trying to implement a scrollbar and preventing content from moving when the scrollbar appear 
i found a solution that make the page scrollable but the scrollbar is invisible
how can i make it visible in the page.
this is my first solution:

```
mat-sidenav-content{
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should add background:transparent;**

Comment: thanks for the response but still doesn't solve the problem